# Can't close db connection with MyBatis

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mybatis

**What I'm doing**:

I've got an AWS Lambda, written in Kotlin (JVM) which reads a message from a queue and writes something on a MySQL table.

I'm using MyBatis for this purpose, and this is a short simplified snippet of what I'm doing inside the Handler:

```
// initializing configuration
val dataSource = PooledDataSource(driver, url, username, password)
val environment = Environment(environmentName, JdbcTransactionFactory(), dataSource)
val configuration = Configuration(environment)

try {
    val builder = SqlSessionFactoryBuilder()
    val session = builder.build(configuration).openSession()
    val mapper: CustomMapper = session.getMapper(CustomMapper::class.java)
    mapper.doSomething()
    session.commit()
} finally {
    session.close()
}
```

**My problem**:

When this Lambda is executed, some connections remain opened on the database. They get destroyed only when the lambda container is automatically destroyed.

Why is this happening since I'm closing all the sessions? Is there anything that I can do in order to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Are you using a connection pool?

Comment: Not using any framework, so I guess I'm not.

Comment: Given you don't show us how you obtain connections, it is not really possible for us to tell either, but that could be an explanation why connections remain open.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've updated my code snippet, the connection is generated everytime I create a session.

Comment: Please show us your configuration.

Comment: @markrotteveel I've added configuration to codesnippet

Comment: The `PooledDataSource` suggests you are using a connection pool, so connections remaining open is entirely expected. When you use a connection pool, the connection obtained is a logical connection wrapping a physical connection. When the session is closed, the logical connection is closed, which returns the physical connection to the connection pool. This is better for performance if your lambda gets executed regularly.

Comment: @markrotteveel the fact is, this doesn't happen, since the connection pool is created inside the lambda handler (which means that every time the lambda is called, the code snipped I posted is executed, so the pool is created everytime. Am I right?

Comment: Likely yes, which would be inefficient. Unfortunately, even with the visibility restricted, this doesn't mean the pool is garbage collected immediately, and it might not even be eligible for garbage collection at all if for example the pool itself started a thread that references the pool (eg for maintenance purposes like detecting connection leaks). You might want to consider initializing this outside of the lambda function itself so it can be reused. It will probably save you on the AWS bill as well.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But if my Lambda scales (which is quite common) it will leave a bunch of opened connection to my database... And a Lambda is meant to be stateless, so why should we cheat with this?

Comment: The lambda itself should be stateless, but for performance having some reusable resources will improve performance and throughput, reducing the need for AWS to scale out, and reducing execution time, which reduces your cost. AWS will spin up a Java process with your lambda, and will keep it running for a while in anticipation of further requests, which will then be handled by the same process! So a connection pool is not bad (just don't configure it with too many idle connections).

Comment: And of course: it would need to be defined outside the lambda itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `PooledDataSource` which creates a connection pool.  Change to `UnpooledDataSource` and that will likely resolve the issue.